# Onclick to submit a form

Tags: javascript, html

There is a PHP-generated HTML 4 transitional page that is used to edit data from a database of a single record. The user has two options: to store changes or delete the record. I use a form with controls (some of them are hidden):

```
<form method="post" action="object_mod.php"><!-- this is another file -->
<!-- inputs follow -->
```

As I want to process two actions ie. delete or save a record I put two submit buttons on the form, before `</FORM>` tag:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save">
<input type="submit" id="btnDelete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Because the user should confirm deletion I added the following `onclick` event:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnDelete" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:deleteRecordConfirm();">
```

(I also tried without `javascript:` and `onclick="javascript:deleteRecordConfirm(); return true;"`), but it doesn't submit a form.

The JS function is

```
function deleteRecordConfirm(){
  if(confirm('Are you sure to delete?')){
    document.getElementById("field_action").value=-1;
    //document.forms[0].submit();
    return true;
  }
}
```

This `field_action` is set to -1 so I know in object_mod.php that I want to delete record rather than save it.

Here go question, *why this form doesn't submit on deletion*?

I think it would be good if a user has Javascript disabled to submit a form anyway, even without confirmation so that is why I use `<INPUT TYPE="submit">` for deletion. Is it a good idea? I was thinking about giving two independent forms (in fact deletion should have only one hidden field with record id) with their own submit buttons, one for deletion and the other for saving.

In fact the page will work in some kind of intranet, with users who I trust and I'm not afraid of hacking or something, but any security remarks are also welcome.

(I tested it on Firefox 19.0 and Javascript console shows no errors, w3c validator says it's a valid page).

Comment: This post as written is not a good fit for stackoverflow's question and answer format. I suggest that if there is a question in #1 above, ask it clearly. Leave the other items to other questions.

Comment: OK, I will edit this. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form should submit according to your code. The only thing I spot is that you should terminate the input tags with `/>`.

BUT... this way, even if the the confirm is cancelled, the form will be submitted. Use the `form.onsubmit` handler and if that returns false, the form will not submit.

I dont think @B3aT's answer is right in that not unconditionally the best way to "externalise" so to say. Many the the simplest is the best.

Comment: The problem is that it does not submit at all - only if I put document.forms[0].submit(). So it works as I want but I don't know why I need this...

Comment: And I said, looking at the code, that the form _should_ submit. Infact, I even made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tYqj9/6/), see your self. Did you terminate the inputs properly?

Comment: Yes. Here above I typed it not copy/pasted and both inputs are `<input xxxx />`. The code executes (`confirm()` is shown). The DTD is `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` which AFAIR doesn't require such terminations, but I have a habit to do it your way.

Comment: So you have confirm but form doesn't submit.

Comment: Yes. The `<input type="submit" />` (for deletion) works exactly like it was `<input type="button" />`. The save button submits properly, but it has no JS code.

Comment: Try to reproduce this in a fiddle. You must be overlooking something.

Answer (score 1):

I  think the best way is to "externalize" the actual form posting.

//make regular buttons (not submit)
//call your own functions (save and delete)
//after you have done your logic do `document.forms["myform"].submit();`

Another solution is to add a checkbox named "delete" and rename the "save" button to "Done or do". And on server side, if "delete" is activated, then ..delete it.

Usually the "delete" is required "per entry" level (same user have multiple records), so you will have to make a separate button/link and eventually do an ajax request/access an URL with ?delete=1&id=3.

You need to make custom yes/no windows or use a jQuery plugin for it, the only browser standard is "confirm".

Comment: You are right, if user has Javascript disabled this field_action would never be set to -1 so making user change a checkbox will work always. Thank you also for your answer for `confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it worked, and this was in fact *very* stupid mistake. The problem was with this button as it was outside the form. I was so sure that I have it inside that I did not review PHP code but copied all from script not the HTML output as I should have done.

As I understand this correctly the line `document.forms[0].submit();` worked but it was not because it was button who submitted the form but `document.form[0]` object itself.

Thank you for all your answers. I will try this `form.onsubmit` hint from Marcell.