# The button of the page triggers the save event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a button on the html page. The purpose of this button is to trigger the "Save As" event on the page after clicking.

Comment: Please show us some code that you have tried first.

Comment: When you say *"to trigger the Save As event"* do you mean you want to allow the client to save something? If so then what are you expecting the client to be able to save? Text from the page? An external document? Please update your question to provide more detail and maybe add what you have tried to accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger 'Save As' in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723868/trigger-save-as-in-browser)

Comment: What I expect is that when the user clicks the button, all the information of the page will be saved, and a static page will be generated. The client can browse the static page without the network.

Answer (score -3):

You have to write a onclick() function in that button tag and write your logic(Save As) in the function.

Reference: [Onclick to submit a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145105/onclick-to-submit-a-form)